# Using MVVM with mutiple controls in a single form

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am new to WPF and starting to learn the MVVM concept.

I am working on an application that create a graphic objects that holds data that is coming from a DB.

I have a group box that contain several labels and comboboxes.

Each should hold a list that is coming from my DB.

For the first combobox I manage to fill it using MVVVM for that specific list.

But how can I fill the other comboboxes if I already initiate  the DataContext with the first list?

Should I create for each ComboBox a ModelView?

And in general, how can I bind few comboboxes to lists dynamically?

```
<Label Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.Column="0"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       Name="lblTiNam">Test Item Name :</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="2"
         Name="tbTiName"
         MinWidth="100"
         MaxWidth="100"></TextBox>
<Label Grid.Row="1"
       Grid.Column="0"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       Name="lblTiExStat">Execution Status :</Label>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.Column="2"
          x:Name="cbTiExStat"
          MinWidth="100"
          MaxWidth="100"
          SelectedValuePath="Content"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Binding QcLists.FieldList}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">

</ComboBox>
<Label Grid.Row="2"
       Grid.Column="0"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       Name="lblTiVersion">Version :</Label>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2"
          Grid.Column="2"
          Name="cbTiVersion"
          MinWidth="100"
          MaxWidth="100"
          SelectedValuePath="Content"
          SelectedIndex="1">
  <ComboBoxItem>To BE Bind From QC</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<Label Grid.Row="3"
       Grid.Column="0"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       Name="lblTiCRID">CRID :</Label>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="3"
          Grid.Column="2"
          Name="cbTiCRID"
          MinWidth="100"
          MaxWidth="100"
          SelectedValuePath="Content">
  <ComboBoxItem>To BE Bind From QC</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<Label Grid.Row="4"
       Grid.Column="0"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       Name="lblTiApplication">Application :</Label>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="4"
          Grid.Column="2"
          Name="cbTiApplication"
          MinWidth="100"
          MaxWidth="100"
          SelectedValuePath="Content">
  <ComboBoxItem>To BE Bind From QC</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<Label Grid.Row="5"
       Grid.Column="0"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       Name="lblTiTestLevel">Test Level :</Label>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="5"
          Grid.Column="2"
          Name="cbTiTestLevel"
          MinWidth="100"
          MaxWidth="100"
          SelectedValuePath="Content">
  <ComboBoxItem>To BE Bind From QC</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

im editing my qustion to add more information:

internal class TestableItemViewModel
{
      public QCLists QcLists
        {
            get { return _qcLists; }
        }

```
    #endregion

   #region Constructor
    public TestableItemViewModel()
    {
        _qcconnect = QCConnection.QCConnect.getInstance();
       // LoadListSettings();
        LoadListSettings( "TS_USER_05");
        SaveCommand = new TestableItemSaveDetailsCommand(this);
    }
    #endregion

    private void LoadListSettings(String FieldName)
    {
        Customization cust = QCConnection.QCConnect.getInstance().GetTD.Customization;
        CustomizationFields fields = cust.Fields;
        CustomizationListNode node;
        CustomizationField field;
        field = fields.get_Field("TEST", FieldName);
        node = field.List.RootNode;
        _qcLists = new QCLists(node.Children, node.Name);
    }
```

}

```
class QCLists:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    TDAPIOLELib.List _fieldList;
    List<String> myTestList;
    String listName;

    public String ListName
    {
        get { return listName; }
        set { listName = value; }
    }

    public List<String> MyTestList
    {
        get { return myTestList; }
        set { myTestList = value; }
    }

    public QCLists(TDAPIOLELib.List List,String name)
    {
        _fieldList = List;
        myTestList = new List<String>();
        listName = name;
    }

    public TDAPIOLELib.List FieldList
    {
        get
        {
            return _fieldList;
        }

        set
        {
            _fieldList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FieldList");

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }

}
```

and for the code behind of the xaml above:

```
 DataContext = new TestableItemViewModel();
```

those are my classes that i used.
as you can see in my xaml,the first combocox is binded to the requierd list and i can see 
the values as i expected.
how do i keep binding the other combobox's?
since i only have one instance of  TestableItemViewModel that is already bind to the first list and the data context is using that list.
i have other lists(4 actually) that i need to bind to the other controls.
of course that im using a query to get the requierd list but this is another issue since the list name can be changed at any given time.
for now i only need to solve the problem with the 5 binding.

Comment: See [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding.](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017) for an example from my blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is if you have a Model for the db record and a model for the list of records i.e.

I will use a Year example for convenience.

```
class YearModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Members

    myService.Year _year;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public myService.Year Year
    {
        get { return _year; }
    }

    public Int32 id
    {
        get { return Year.id; }
        set
        {
            Year.id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("id");
        }
    }

    public String Code
    {
        get { return Year.Code; }
        set
        {
            Year.Code = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Code");
        }
    }

#region Construction

    public YearModel()
    {
        this._year = new SchoolMonitor_Service.Year
        {
            id = 0,
            Code = "",
        };
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then the list

```
class YearListModel
{
    myService.myServcieClient service = new myService.myServcieClient();

    #region Members

    private ObservableCollection<YearModel> _years;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<YearModel> Years
    {
        get { return _years; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Construction

    public YearListModel()
    {
        _years = new ObservableCollection<YearModel>();

        foreach (SchoolMonitor_Service.Year y in service.GetYearList())
        {
            _years.Add(new YearModel
            {
                id = y.id,
                Code = y.Code
            }
                            );
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then you create a ViewModel getting all the lists you need I have added YearGroups as an example:

```
class YearFormViewModel
{
    public YearListModel YearList { get; set; }
    public YearGroupListModel YearGroupList { get; set; }

    public YearFormViewModel()
    {
        YearList = new YearListModel;
        YearGroupList = new YearGroupListModel();
    }
}
```

You can then get the ViewModel in the window/page:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myProject.Models"


<Page.Resources>
    <local:YearFormViewModel x:Key="myViewModel" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Then bind accordingly:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbYears" 
                      DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myViewModel}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YearList.Years}"
                      SelectedValuePath="id" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="Code"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="cbYearGroups" 
                      DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myViewModel}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YearGroupList.YearGroups}"
                      SelectedValuePath="id" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="Code"/>
```

Comment: thanks alot.this is working great.i was afraid that i will had to specify new object for each list.since i wanted it to be dynamically so i will be able to add lists in the future withot the need to hardcode it.but thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

To bind combo boxes in MVVM paradigm - You should add to your ViewModel class a list, and populate it with the items you want to display in the combo box. Let me explain with an example:

in ViewModel (which should implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
public BindingList<string> Cities { get; set; }
```

Since you say that the values for the combo boxes are being loaded in from the database, you will need to make sure to raise PropertyChanged on "Cities" when the values are finished loading - this way the view knows to refresh anything bound to property "Cities".

in View:

```
<Combobox ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" />
```

Comment: How about showing the InotifyPropertyChanged to add to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that in WPF and MVVM, we *don't* set the `DataContext` of individual controls. Instead, we have an instance of a view model class that has all of the properties that we need to display in our UI and we set *that* as the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`, or view.

In this way, all of the controls will have access to all of the properties in the view model and so we then simply set the `ItemsSource` properties of each control to the relevant collection property in the view model.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly you want to add combobox's  to your string dynamically.

CS :

```
public class CollectionWrapper<T>  
{
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }

    private IList<T> _collection;

    public IList<T> Collection
    {
        get { return _collection; }
        set { _collection = value; }
    }     

    public string DisplayMemeberPath
    {
       get;set;
    } 


}


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<string> GetNewList()
    {
        return new List<string>
        {
           "1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4"
        };
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Add(new CollectionWrapper<string> { Collection = GetNewList(), Title = (Items.Count + 1 ).ToString() , DisplayMemeberPath="Content"}); 
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CollectionWrapper<string>> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<CollectionWrapper<string>> Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (_items == null)
                _items = new ObservableCollection<CollectionWrapper<string>>();
            return _items;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate  x:Key="listItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Content="{Binding Title}"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding DisplayMemeberPath}"/>

        </Grid>            
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Button Content="Add List" Click="Button_Click"/>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```